# Change column titles in invoice2 class

Tags: invoice, invoice2

According to the `invoice2` manual I can change the variables used for printing column titles etc. through a bunch of "localization options" which all have the prefix `invoice2-`, like e.g. `invoice2-item`.

However, trying to use these results in errors of the type

`keyvalue error: "option-unknown" Unknown option 'invoice2-item' for package invoice2."`

Unfortunately this feature isn't used in any of the examples in the manual, so it's not clear to me if I've done anything wrong or if this is a bug in the package.

The MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[invoice2-item=Foo]{invoice2}
\begin{document}
\begin{invoice}
\invoicesingleitem{Bar}{2.5}
\end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

but I've tested it with a number of other `invoice2-` variables as well.

The regular configuration variables work as expected.

Comment: Looking further through the various manuals and then `invoice2`'s source code I think this is a bug (or rather a documented-but-missing feature) in the package, which I've filed on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/no-preserve-root/invoice2/issues/12). The workaround is to use `\DeclareTranslation{<language>}{<variable>}{<text-to-be-used>}`

Answer (score 0):

For me it just worked with the \DeclareTranslation command, but don't just fill in "item" for {} but the whole thing (to be found in the invoice2-documentation):
\DeclareTranslation{}{invoice2-item}{<new name for "item">}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- show a short compilable TeX code including your solution for a fast proof ...